# How can I add a class to body but to choose name in Wordpress backend?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to ask how I can make a option in backend to add a specific class to body on a category page. My idea is that i want to have a color sheme (Headlines, links, backgrounds..) to be the same color as the selected category.

For example when I'm on a category page with listed subcategories and the posts underneath, when i click on the post i want the post template to have the same color sheme as the parent subcategory and the category.

Is there a simple way to do this with Wordpress?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Check this out - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/add-category-name-body_class/

Comment: Can I add a attribute metabox (text) to a page and to categories and apply this class to the body?

Answer (score 0):

add this to `functions.php`. It will add `category-slug` to your `body class`

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    if(is_category()){
        $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
        $classes = array_merge( $classes, array( $cat->slug ) );
    }
    return $classes;
} );
```

now you can  do `css` based on your category's `slug`.

Comment: Hi @Jared Chu, 

When I insert your code into my functions.php i get this PHP Error Message: 

https://i.imgur.com/j6rHKsf.png

Can you tell me how to fix that?

Comment: I have updated my answer but I think it's a conflict with your current theme because I tested it on my website

Comment: Hi @Jared Chu, 

I see now the category class in body, but I dont see it in the Post under this category? I need the same color sheme for a category --> subcategory --> post to have the same look and feel.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: It's only possible to category --> post